# List Address Book

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is my list empty when I ask python on the shell to print it a 2nd time?

```
def name():
    name = str(input("Name:"))
    return name

def phone():
    phone = str(input("Phone Number: "))
    return phone

def email():
    email = str(input("Email: "))
    return email
```

Then I created a `join` function in order for me to add all the data to a list:

```
def join(lst, name, phone, email): 
    name = name()

if name in lst:
    print("Name already in")
    phone = phone()

if phone in lst:
    print("Phone already exists")
    email = email()

if email in lst:
    print("Email already exists!")
    lst += [name]
    lst += [phone]
    lst += [email]
    print("Added!")
return lst
```

Function to list every entry on the Address book:

```
def print_list(lst):
    print(lst)
```

And the menu looks like this:

```
def menu():
    print("1-New Contact")
    print("2-Print list")
    option = int(input("Option:"))
return option

def repeat(lst):
    option = menu()
    while option < 2 and option >= 1:
        if option == 1:
            lst = join(lst, name, phone, email)
        elif opcao == 2:
            lst = print_list(lst)
        else:
            print("Invalid option")
        opcao = menu()

lst = []
call = repeat(lst)
print(call)
```

Comment: Could you please provide a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of several code snippets? If you code is very long please narrow it down to the parts you really need in order to make your problem reproducible. Additionally, please fix your  syntax errors (indentation and strings).

Comment: Your indentation is off, you're missing a quote, and you mask a function.

Comment: There´s no problem with identation on the original file, the program runs fine, the only issue is when I run the menu a 2nd time and ask it to print the list again. @TigerhawkT3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by printing you mean this part of the code: `lst=print_list(lst)` and your list is in `lst` variable.

What you do here is assign the return value of `print_list` function to your `lst` variable after the first call. This will set it to None as `print_list` doesn't return any value explicitly. When you try to print the second time, `lst` is None and nothing is printed.

You should not assign to `lst` and simply call `print_list(lst)` without assigning the return value:

```
elif opcao==2: print_list(lst)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Szymon it works now as it should.

Comment: Do you know how can I make it print a list of the input names that goes A-Z?

Comment: This is a separate question - ask a new one, please.

Comment: Unfortunately Stackoverflow doesn´t allow me to until 4 days @Szymon